# Batch - loop misses commands after few passes

Tags: loops, batch-file

I tried to write simple program. It should find .pak files (zip in this case but with changed etension), extract them and pack them using arc.

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.pak) do ren %%~i %%~ni.arc
for /r %%i in (*.arc) do (
mkdir %%~ni
cd %%~ni
..\arc.exe x -o+ "%%~i" //extract archive at current location//
del "%%~i"
..\arc.exe a -m9 -r "%%~i" *.* //pack files and folders in current folder and create
archive at specific location//
cd..
RD /s /q %%~ni
)
pause
```

Arc command works i'm sure about that. Everything works perfect untill few passes later. It seems that it suddenly stop doing cd.. command because it starts creating folder then folder inside then again and again.

Locations of files:
...\arc.exe 
...\program.bat 
...\file1.pak 
...\folder1\file2.pak 
...\folder2\file3.pak 
etc for pack

I tried also

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%i in (*.pak) do ren %%~i %%~ni.arc
for /r %%i in (*.arc) do (
mkdir %%~ni
cd %%~ni
..\arc.exe x -o+ "%%~i"
del "%%~i"
..\arc.exe a -m9 -r "%%~i" *.*
cd..
RD /s /q %%~ni
)
pause
```

The same result

Comment: Doing anything even slightly complex with DOS batch files is a pain.  Are you able to switch to PowerShell?  If so, I suggest looking into that.

Comment: No because i want to do "inverse" program which can be used by anyone without installing addidional things.

Comment: Are there any sub-sub-…-folders?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to enable delayed expansion since it will corrupt file names if they happen to contain `!` character.

I believe your problem is simply you haven't quoted your path/file names. Spaces and special characters in path/name will cause problems unless they are quoted.

This is completely untested, but I think it may fix you problem:

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.pak) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.arc"
for /r %%i in (*.arc) do (
  mkdir "%%~ni"
  cd "%%~ni"
  ..\arc.exe x -o+ "%%~i" //extract archive at current location//
  del "%%i"
  ..\arc.exe a -m9 -r "%%i" *.* //pack files and folders in current folder and create archive at specific location//
  cd..
  rd /s /q "%%~ni"
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfornately it still doesn't work. At some point it say that it can't find specific file. Probably at rd /s /q "%%~ni". It created many folder nside and inside one folder again and path of this is so long you can't even open all of them. The strange thing is that: if i rewrite this loop for each file (even 10) using full path for %%~i and file name for %%i it works...